# Prove that : $\int_{a}^{b} (\varphi (t)-\lambda_{\varphi}\theta(t))\,dt =0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Prove that :

$$\int_{a}^{b} (\varphi (t)-\lambda_{\varphi}\theta(t))\,dt =0$$

Where :

$$\theta , \varphi \in D(]a,b[) 
:\text{functions test} $$
Such that :

$$\lambda_{\varphi}=\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b} \varphi (t)dt$$

And :

$$\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b} \theta (t)  dt=1$$

- also prove that $$\exists\psi\in D(]a,b[) , \varphi =\psi '+\lambda_{\varphi}\theta $$
  My try :

$$\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b} (\varphi (t)-\lambda_{\varphi}\theta(t))dt =\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b} \varphi (t)-\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b} \varphi (t)\theta (t) dtdt$$
From here how I can complete ?

Can you assist

---

Thanks!

Comment: $\int_a^b \varphi(t)-\lambda_\varphi\theta(t)dt=\int_a^b \varphi(t)dt-\lambda_\varphi\int_a^b\theta(t)dt=\lambda_\varphi-\lambda_\varphi=0$

Comment: @Reveillark Thank you very much sir , im thankful!

Comment: Should "functions text" be "test functions"?